# Suppress an unnecessary space in a tabular

Tags: tables, spacing

In this MWE there is a unnecessary space under the tikzpicture.
How to suppress it ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tikz}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{@{}X@{}|}}\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,\linewidth) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tabulars insert always a strut. So you need to ensure that your tikzpicture have at least a depth of 0.3\normalbaselineskip:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tikz}

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|*{5}{@{}X@{}|}}\hline
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0.3\normalbaselineskip)}]
\draw (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,\linewidth) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
&&&&\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]